# WCF Transport Security, Message Encryption with Anonymous Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to setup a WCF client to talk with a service.  The connection needs to be https (Transport Security) and we need to do message encryption with a public key.  We do not have a client certificate to present.

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
// This is failing because the private key for client authentication is not being set
// binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCrediential;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
```

And then to set the public key I'm doing

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = certificate;
```

Where certificate is an X509Certificate2 object with just the public key.

When I do this it does not encrypt the message.  Using Fiddler I see the raw text of the message come across the wire and the service gives an error because it is expecting an encrypted message.

Edit: Added comment about TransportWithMessageCrediential

Comment: Usually encrypting data once is enough for most people. Do you really want both TLS and message security?

Comment: Yes, because it protects against a man in the middle attack.  We are sending PII and it is required to have the message encrypted as well.

Comment: I think - for WSHttpBinding - that you can only set Security to `Transport` or `Message`. You can't have both. You also seem to confuse encryption with credentials. Credentials don't encrypt the message. They tell the server who the caller is. As for Fiddler being able to see your messages, did you let it install a trusted certificate? Because if you do that, then it can do a man-in-the-middle 'attack'. To protect against that, you can do 'certificate pinning', where you check that the server's certificate is what you expect.

Comment: WSHttpBinding does allow for both (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/security-of-wshttpbinding).  The Fiddle did install the root CA cert, which does allow me to decrypt and see https messages, but it would still show me if it was encrypted using message encryption (hence the need for both).

Comment: "Yes, because it protects against a man in the middle attack". TLS should also be able to do this as it'll require a certificate which must be trusted by the client. A man in the middle will only be successful if the client also trusts the cert of the "Middleman". This should only happen in case of a https inspection by some organisation that has access to the clients cert store.

Comment: I agree that it should be enough as long as no one can decrypt the TLS traffic.  The request that I have is to encrypt the message too.

Comment: The only binding I can find that supports both at the same time is NetMsmqBinding where you can set Security to `Both`. I doubt you can use that binding for SOAP over HTTP/HTTPS though. Those bindings only support one or the other out of the box. You might be able to make your own binding that does both. Your time would probably be better spent trying to convince the people making the request that TLS is enough. "If it's good enough for banks and governments, then it's probably good enough for us..."

Comment: I'm sorry but we disagree.  TLS is not the same as Message Encryption and I know for a fact it is not good enough for government.  My client is requiring we do Message Encryption and I agree with them.

Comment: OK. Your choice. Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920097/wcf-binding-with-both-transport-and-message-security

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have solved this.  We are using a CustomBinding to set it all up.

This setups up the binding

```
private Binding GetBinding()
{
    var binding = new CustomBinding()
    // This could be configured per service
    MessageVersion messageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;

    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement messageEncodingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(messageVersion, Encoding.UTF8);
    binding.Elements.Add(messageEncodingElement)
    if (/* Encryption is needed */)
    {
        SecurityBindingElement securityElement = securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateAnonymousForCertificateBindingElement();
        securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = GetEncryptionAlgorithm(); // This will return which algorithm is desired
        securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false; // This is because our services were returning an error when it was included
        binding.Elements.Add(securityElement);

    HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
    if (/* If Windows Authentication is required */)
        httpsTransportElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
    binding.Elements.Add(httpsTransportElement)
    return binding;
}
```

Then to use the client

```
// By default WCF will check that the DnsName of the certificate matchs the DNS name of the endpoint we need to override this.
// We did want want to require an appliction to use the same cert that is for SSL as for message encryption
EndpointIdentity endpointIdentity = null;
if (endpoint.EncryptionCertificate != null)
    endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(endpoint.EncryptionCertificate.GetCertificate().GetNameInfo(X509NameType.DnsName, false));
else
    endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(endpoint.Address);


AddressHeader[] header = null;
using (var client = new portTypeClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(address), endpointIdentity, header)))
{
    if (/* Encryption is needed */)
    {
        var certificate = LoadX509Certificate();
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = certificate;
    }
}
```